# If we say "Socrates", "Hippocrates", etc, why don't we say "Aristoteles"? Why "Aristotle"?

Tags: names, transliteration, greek

If Σωκράτης is transliterated as "[Socrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates)", and Ἱπποκράτης is transliterated as "[Hippocrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocrates)", and other Greek names ending with -ης are transliterated as ending with "-es", why isn't Ἀριστοτέλης transliterated "Aristoteles" instead of "[Aristotle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle)"?

Comment: As well ask why Plato and not Platon?

Comment: Aristoteles has five syllables and is a relatively long name. Probably this was the cause that a shortened form was adopted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Aristotle* is the anglicized form of the the transliterated *Aristoteles*. According to this article on [historical personal names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicisation#Historical_personal_names), at one point in time many foreign language names were given an anglicized version:

> In the past, the names of people from other language areas were anglicised to a higher extent than today. This was the general rule for names of Latin or (classical) Greek origin. Today, the anglicised name forms are often retained for the more common persons, like Aristotle for *Aristoteles*, and Adrian or (later) Hadrian for *Hadrianus*. However, less well-known persons from the antiquity now are often given their full name (in the nominative case).

I think that some of the anglicization may also depend on what Latin names each person was given. Though this is not, by any means, the best source, this [list of names](http://www.20000-names.com/male_h_names_3.htm) lists that *Hippocrates* and *Hippokrates* are the Latin and Greek forms of the name. Aristotle, on the other hand, is listed as *Aristoteles* and *Aristotle*.

So the conclusion I put forth is that these names were all anglicized based on other names that the philosophers were known by (here, Latin).